# Append HTML in angular js giving errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, active-directory, angularjs-ng-click

I am a newbie in angularjs and was trying to append the data in the view on click event.

The following is the code I have written:

Html

```
<div id="space-for-buttons">
            <input type="hidden" id="hdnTopRatedPage" value="0" ng-update-hidden>
          <div class='item' ng-repeat='p in programs.rated' home-tab-item watchable="p" ></div>
          </div>
          <div class = 'rated-spin' ng-show = 'programs.rated == 0 && ratedLoaded == false'> </div>
          <div ng-show="programs.rated == 0  && ratedLoaded == true" class="noResultsBlock">No Results for Rated.</div>
          <div class='clearfix'></div>


          <div ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-app="woi">
            <yes style='background-color: brown;padding-right: 61px;'></yes>

           </div>
```

Directive:

```
var pageno=1;

function MainCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.count = 0;
}

//Directive that returns an element which adds buttons on click which show an alert on click.Here we can put
woi.directive("yes",['userAPI','$rootScope', function(userAPI,$rootScope){
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        template: "<a ng-click='str()' addbuttons>please click on me</a>"
    }
}]);

//Directive for adding buttons on click that show an alert on click
woi.directive("addbuttons",['$rootScope','userAPI','$compile', function($rootScope,userAPI,$compile){
    return function(scope, element, attrs){
        element.bind("click", function(){
            scope.count++;
            alert("hII")
            //var abc= scope.loadRated(pageno);
            userAPI.topRated({userid: $rootScope.getUser().userid}, function (r, $scope, div){
                if(!$rootScope.device.isMobile && !$rootScope.device.isTablet && !$rootScope.device.isTouch ) {
                     var topRatedList = r.gettopratedhomepage.topratedprogrammelist;
                    console.log(r)

                    var str='';
                    for(var i=0;i<topRatedList.length;i++)
                    {
                        // str+="topRatedList[i].actualname";

                        var programNameEncode= topRatedList[i].programmename   // | encodeUrl;
                        var program=topRatedList[i].programmename;
                        var channelId=topRatedList[i].channelid;
                        var programId=topRatedList[i].programmeid;
                        var channel=topRatedList[i].channeldisplayname;
                        var channelNameEncode=topRatedList[i].channeldisplayname       //| encodeUrl;
                        var startTime=topRatedList[i].starttime;
                        var favourite=topRatedList[i].isfavorite;
                        var reminder=topRatedList[i].isreminder;
                        var watchlist=topRatedList[i].iswatchlist;
                        var duration=topRatedList[i].duration;
                        var imageFile=topRatedList[i].imagefilepath;
                        var startTime= topRatedList[i].starttime;
                        var duration= topRatedList[i].duration;
                        var isReco=topRatedList[i].isrecommended;         // This is for reco


                         str+=" <div class='item'>" ;
                         str+="<div class=\"thumb\">";
                  //     str+="<div ng-show=\""+isReco=='1'+"\" class=\"favorite-ribbon\"></div>";
                         str+="<div class=\"player\"></div>";
                         str+="<div class='image' style='background-image:url('"+imageFile+"');'>";
                        str+="<img src='"+imageFile+"'/>";
                         str+="<a ng-click=\'playVideo("+program+"\,$event)' ng-show='hasVideo()' class='play' style='cursor:pointer'></a>";

                        str+=  "<a ng-href=\"#!/program/"+programNameEncode+"\"  ng-show=\"!hasVideo()\" class=\"noPlay\" ng-click=\"EncodeUrlWithDash("+program+",$event,'programme',"+channelId+","+programId+","+startTime+")\"></a></div>";

                       str+="<span class='time' ng-show='duration'>\""+duration+"\"</span>";

                       str+="<div class='user-actions' ng-controller='UserController'>";

                         str+="<a live-tooltip='Add to Favorite'  ng-click='toggleFavorite(p, $event)'  class='btn btn-small btn-purple-blue' ng-class=\""+{active:favourite == '1'}+"\>";
                         str+="<i class='icon-favorite'></i></a>";

                         str+="<a live-tooltip='Reminder Alerts'  ng-click='toggleReminder(p, $event)'  class='btn btn-small btn-purple-blue' ng-class=\""+{active:reminder == '1'}+"\>";
                         str+="<i class='icon-reminder'></i></a>";

                         str+="<a live-tooltip='Add to Watchlist' ng-click='addToWatchlist(p, $event)'  class='btn btn-small btn-purple-blue' ng-class=\""+{active:watchlist == '1'}+"\>";
                         str+="<i class='icon-watchlist'></i></a></div>";  //end of user controller div

                       str+="</div>";    // end of thumb div

                        str+="<div class='text-wrapper'>";
                        str+="<h2 multiline-overflow><a title='"+program+"' href='#!/program/"+programNameEncode+"' ng-click=\""+"EncodeUrlWithDash("+program+",$event,'programme',"+channelId+","+programId+","+startTime+")"+"/ >\""+program+"\"</a></h2>";

                        str+="<p class='infoChannel' live-tooltip-single-line= '{{channel}}'><a href='#!/channel/"+channelNameEncode+"' ng-click=\""+"EncodeUrlWithDash("+channel+",$event,'channel',"+channelId+","+programId+")"+"/>\""+channel+"\"</a></p>";
                        str+="<p class='info'>\""+startTime+"\"</p>";

                      str+="</div></div>";  //end of the main div

     //EXTRA LINE
           //          str+=" <div class='item' ng-repeat='topRatedList[i] in programs.rated' home-tab-item watchable='topRatedList[i]' ></div>" ;
                        alert("The below value is of str")
                        alert(str);
                        angular.element(document.getElementById('space-for-buttons')).append($compile(str)(scope));
                    }
                    alert("The below value is of str")

                    // The above code is required to append data into the division(loadrated)..

                }
            });
        });
    };
}]);
```

however the code is running properly(ie it goes through the entire directive)..But data is not displayed ie appending.

Instead it goes into another directive which I have called hometab directive and giving issues.

I dont know why this is happening.

Please help me out

Comment: It would be easier to help you with this if you provide a Plunker, but have you considered using ng-show or ng-hide to do this instead of adding html in your directive?

Comment: @lmyers..Ok..Will try out in plunker..but i dont want to load it before hand and want to call only on click event..Thats why I am not using ng-show and hide

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier for you to create a Plunker for this issue [here](http://plnkr.co/)

Concerning your directive, without having full access to your files, it is considered good practice to hold all functionality and styles within the scope of it. Therefore, the only thing that should be in the HTML is the directive element only. Everything else, should thus be within the directive js.

Just as well, your `ng-show/hide` have very intensive expressions within them. I would try and chop'em down a bit. Additionally, the HTML syntax with quotes are using " " in some instances and ' ' with mixed spaces in others.

I have seen this throw errors in the past, though it is valid to use single or double. The preferred usage is the double quotes "" on everything in HTML and single quotes for JS files. I would just make sure you are using one or the other and not both.

You can check this article about the specific rules [here](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/qattr.html)